# Check success of remote file append via ssh

Tags: ssh, cat, append

I like to periodically append some data to a remote file via `ssh` and remove it locally. Like:

```
cat some_lines_to_append.txt | ssh user@example.com 'cat >> all_lines_collected.txt'
rm some_lines_to_append.txt
```

Now I like to make sure `some_lines_to_append.txt` is only removed, if the lines where successfully transfered. How to do that?

Does `>>` create some sort of error return code by itself on failure, or does `cat` in this case, and will `ssh` deliver that return code?

Will `shh` itself deliver non-zero return codes in any occasion that it was finished prematurely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cat` will return 0 (zero) on success.

According to `ssh` manual :

> EXIT STATUS
>
> ```
>   ssh exits with the exit status of the remote command or with 255 if an error occurred.
> ```

So, in your case it is enough

```
cat some_lines_to_append.txt |
   ssh user@example.com 'cat >> all_lines_collected.txt' &&
   rm some_lines_to_append.txt ||
   echo 'Error occurred.'
```

Comment: Cool. Also someone else told me `ssh` would in fact pass the return code of the invoked commands. So maybe the pipe would just work without capturing the return code via `echo $?`and `rc=...`?

Comment: It seems just `cat some_lines_to_append.txt | ssh user@example.com 'cat >> all_lines_collected.txt' && rm some_lines_to_append.txt`  would just work better then first expected by me...

Comment: Yes, `ssh` exits with the exit status of the remote command or with 255 if an
error occurred. rc=$(... code needed when more complex remote commands executed and you want to catch some errors in a middle, but in your case  `cat some_lines_to_append.txt | ssh user@example.com 'cat >> all_lines_collected.txt' && rm some_lines_to_append.txt || echo 'Error occurred'` is enough.

Comment: I edited my answer so it should reflect your particular needs without extra unnecessary information.

Comment: Cool. Sometimes, the first shot is working well despite the expectation.